# How do I customize CoreDNS with Azure Kubernetes Service for multiple environments and services?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, coredns

I am working on an existing AKS cluster that contains multiple services that communicate with each other. This is currently working, but the communication is using an external name. This means that these internal requests will hairpin.

The environment that I am working with is a pre-production cluster that is hosting several environments, each in its own namespace. There is a single nginx ingress load balancer (single external IP), and each namespace has an ingress that maps a host to the environment services. My hosts are in the form of `<env>.domain.com`. The paths are in the form of `/api/<service>` which are mapped to the respective service.

What I would like to accomplish is setting up a ConfigMap that would rewrite the egress requests and avoid hair-pinning. For example, a request from `service1` to `service2` would be `https://<env>.domain.com/api/service2/`. The map or maps that are configured would then need to rewrite this request to the correct internal service for the environment and service.

I have read [Customize CoreDNS with Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/coredns-custom), and unsure how to apply their samples to my situation. Their example is as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns-custom
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  test.server: | # you may select any name here, but it must end with the .server file extension
    <domain to be rewritten>.com:53 {
        errors
        cache 30
        rewrite name substring <domain to be rewritten>.com default.svc.cluster.local
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
          pods insecure
          upstream
          fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        forward .  /etc/resolv.conf # you can redirect this to a specific DNS server such as 10.0.0.10, but that server must be able to resolve the rewritten domain name
    }
```

My plan is to make the following changes:

1. Update the above config with the following line:

```
rewrite name regex ([^.]+)\.domain\.com {1}.svc.cluster.local
```

2. Add ingress rules for `<env>.svc.cluster.local` for each environment

This is on a pre-production envrionment, so I have some leeway for trial and error with the configuration. However, I'm hoping to confirm that I am on the right path. Am I correct that the above changes would rewrite my internal requests to an internal name and be captured by the ingress resources with the internal name as the host?

Comment: your question is bit confusing in what you are trying to achieve. Do you want service in one namespace communicate with service present in another namespace? Moreover CoreDNS stuff is for making your pods resolve to your private DNS records that is hosted on a separate DNS server outside of kubernetes.

Comment: @vishal.k, The services would only communicate with other services in the same namespace. The namespaces isolate my pre-production environments (i.e. dev, demo, test). They use external names to make the API calls (i.e. `<env>.domain.com/api/service1/action`, `<env>.domain.com/api/service2/action`). The article that I referenced in the OP and [Custom DNS Entries For Kubernetes](https://coredns.io/2017/05/08/custom-dns-entries-for-kubernetes/) document using CoreDNS to avoid hairpins by rewriting requests to external names to internal names. Please let me know if this is still unclear.

Comment: okay I get an idea now, I don't have an answer right now, Lemme research some more and update here If I get a solution.